# Let $p$ be a prime number and consider the set of numbers $S = {1, 2, . . . , p − 1}$. Let $a ∈ S$. Prove the following two claims.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

(a) Prove that no two numbers from the list are congruent modulo $p$
1$·$a, 2$·$a, 3$·$a, ... $(p-2)·a$, $(p-1)·a$

I think I am suppose to assume there exist two number $(x,y)$ that are congruent modulo $p$, so $xa = pq+r$ and $ya = pk+r$. But I am not sure where to go from here.

(b) Prove that there exists $b∈S$ such that $b·a ≡_p1$.

For this one I am not sure how to start. I tried setting $b·a = p·q + 1$, how can I use this to prove the statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

If two elements of $S$, say $ma$ and $na$ are congruent mod $(P)$, their difference, $(m-n)a$ is a multiple of $p$.

That is not possible because $p$ is prime and both $a$ and $m-n$ are less than $p$. We know that if a prime number divides a product it has to divide at least one of the factors.

The second part of the problem is that why one of the remainders is $1$.

Since there are only $p-1$ non-zero remainders and the $p-1$ elements of S have different remainders,one remainder must be $1$

That is $a$ and $m$ are multiplicative inverse, mod $(p) $ for some $1\le m \le p-1$

Comment: How does multiplicative inverse work in this question? if $a$ is a positive int, won't $m$ be $\frac{1}{m}$? and that is less than $1$. Also there is no $m$ in the second part of the question, so how does that help to solve the remainder must be 1

Comment: Multiplicative inverses in modular arithmetic do not work the way they do in ordinary arithmetic. As an example, look at residues mod 5. They are $0,1,2,3,4$. $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. But $1\cdot 1=1\equiv 1\mod{5}$, $2\cdot 3=6\equiv 1\mod{5}$, and $4\cdot 4=16\equiv 1\mod{5}$. Two residues that multiply to give a result that is $\equiv 1\mod{5}$ are said to be multiplicative inverses, just as $m$ and $\frac{1}{m}$ are multiplicative inverses because they multiply to $1$ in ordinary arithmetic. So $\mod{5}$, $1$ and $4$ are their own multiplicative inverses, and $2,3$ are inverses.